# Как запустить jar файл?

Tags: java

При дабл клике у меня ошибка cant find or load main class, причём это на любом jar файле, т.е. я так понимаю проблема может быть в настройках javы на компьютере? может нужно настроить переменные среды?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: @AK Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Спасибо за наставление. Не буду оправдываться тем, что я новенький (две недели не срок), но скажу, что нечасто так делаю. Видел уже на мете обсуждения, что ответы лучше комментариев, но во многих случаях людям достаточно дать небольшую подсказку (да что там -- порой даже просто формулирование вопроса для so очень многое даёт для ответа), а дальше они справятся сами. В данном случае слишком много вариантов у топикстартера, поэтому я и ограничился ссылкой.

Answer (score 5):

В jar файле есть файл Manifest.mf(в папке META-INF), в нем нужно указать имя главного класса, откройте свой jar-файл любым архиватором, если не обнаружите там файл Manifest.mf, или же в самом файле Manifest.mf не будет строки:

```
Main-Class: [имя вашего главного класса]
```

Значит сборка выполнена не корректно.
Второй вариант, в ваших классах отсутствует точка входа (главный метод):

```
public static void main(String[] args){...
```

должен быть один такой метод для того чтобы класс содержащий его считался главным.